# Thread.sleep NOT working Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have an objectAnimator

```
final ObjectAnimator anim = (ObjectAnimator) AnimatorInflater
                .loadAnimator(getActivity(), R.anim.flip);
        anim.setTarget(tvDebitAmount);
        anim.setDuration(3000);
        anim.start();
```

I need this to work in a loop, with some gap. I mean , once this animation finishes I need to call anim.start again after a wait of 4000 ms.

I tried putting it in a infinite loop , and put thread.sleep() after anim.start(). It's not working(whole screen is not responding). How can I make it wait/sleep ?

Comment: Thread.sleep is supposed to sleep the thread in which you call it.  When you sleep the GUI thread you prevent it from doing other things such as updating the screen or responding to events.  In other words Thread.sleep is working correctly.  The screen will not update until you return from your event handling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Thread.sleep()` blocks the current thread which is the UI thread and you don't want that.

To make the animation work the way you want, just wrap it in an animation set that runs 4000 ms longer while the actual animation in the set still takes only 3000 ms. Then set the animation repeat mode to `RESTART` and repeat count to `INFINITE`.

Comment: Thanks! anim.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE); helped me. I didn't use any loop. Still I couldn't make it wait before repeating. Increasing setDuration is just making the animation slow.

Comment: Updated the answer to clarify: Wrap the animation in an animation set that runs for 7000ms and put the 3000ms animation in it.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) or else use the [`Timer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html). So that it works in seperate thread with out disturbing the main thread. Get an example about timer [here](http://writecodeeasy.blogspot.in/2012/08/androidtutorial-timer-p1.html).